# javascript syntax: function calls and using parenthesis

Tags: javascript, syntax

why does this work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 

function myAlert(){
    alert('magic!!!');
}


if(document.addEventListener){   
    myForm.addEventListener('submit',myAlert,false); 
}else{   
    myForm.attachEvent('onsubmit',myAlert); 
}
// -->
</script>
```

but not this ????

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 

function myAlert(){
    alert('magic!!!');
}


if(document.addEventListener){   
    myForm.addEventListener('submit',myAlert(),false); 
}else{   
    myForm.attachEvent('onsubmit',myAlert()); 
}
// -->
</script>
```

the difference being the use of parenthesis when calling the `myAlert` function.

the error I get..

> "htmlfile: Type mismatch." when compiling via VS2008.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The **()** after a function means to *execute* the function itself and return it's value. Without it you simply have the function, which can be useful to pass around as a callback.

```
var f1 = function() { return 1; }; // 'f1' holds the function itself, not the value '1'
var f2 = function() { return 1; }(); // 'f2' holds the value '1' because we're executing it with the parenthesis after the function definition

var a = f1(); // we are now executing the function 'f1' which return value will be assigned to 'a'
var b = f2(); // we are executing 'f2' which is the value 1. We can only execute functions so this won't work
```

Comment: Huh. "function() {return 1;}();" is a syntax error, but "(function() {return 1;}())" is not. Silly JavaScript and your seperate function statements and expressions...

Comment: @Simon: "function() {return 1;}();" is a syntax error only when not assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

The [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.addEventListener) function expects a function or an object implementing `EventListener` as the second argument, not a function call.

When the `()` are added to a function name, it is a function invocation rather than the function itself.

**Edit:** As indicated in the other responses and in the comments, it is possible to return functions in Javascript.

So, for something interesting, we could try the following. From the original `myAlert`, we can change it a little to return a different message, depending on the parameters:

```
function myAlert(msg)
{
    return function()
    {
        alert("Message: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Here, notice that the function actually returns a function. Therefore, in order to invoke that function, the extra `()` will be required.

I wrote a little HTML and Javascript to use the above function. (Please excuse my unclean HTML and Javascript, as it's not my domain):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myAlert(msg)
{
    return function()
    {
        alert("Message: " + msg);
    }
}

</script>

<html>
<body>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="myAlert('Clicked Button1')()">
<input type="button" value="Button2" onclick="myAlert('Clicked Button2')()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Two buttons are shown, and each will call the `myAlert` function with a different parameter. Once the `myAlert` function is called, it itself will return another `function` so that must be invoked with an extra set of parenthesis.

End result is, clicking on `Button1` will show a message box with the message `Message: Clicked Button1`, while clicking on `Button2` will show a message box saying `Message: Clicked Button2`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the parenthesis you're actually invoking the function and you're sending the function result (in this case undefined because myAlert doesn't have a return value) as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that functions are first-class objects. You can toss them around like any other object. Here's a nice concise example of why this is cool, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function#Javascript):

```
function makeDerivative( f, deltaX ) {
    var deriv = function(x) { 
       return ( f(x + deltaX) - f(x) )/ deltaX;
    }

    return deriv;
}

var cos = makeDerivative( Math.sin, 0.000001);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.addEventListener){   
    myForm.addEventListener('submit',myAlert(),false); 
}else{   
    myForm.attachEvent('onsubmit',myAlert()); 
}
```

using `myAlert()` here is giving the returned value of the function, not the function itself.

Consider this:

```
function bob() {
    return "hello world";
}

alert(bob());
```

the alert is going to use the value returned by the function `bob`.

If you want to pass additional parameters in you addEventListener, try this:

```
if(document.addEventListener){   
    myForm.addEventListener('submit',function(event) {
        myAlert(event,myOtherParamater); 
    },false); 
}else{   
    myForm.attachEvent('onsubmit',function () {
        myAlert(window.event,myOtherParameter); 
    }); 
}
```

javascript uses first-class functions and can thus be passed as parameters to functions which is what the addEventListener and attachEvent methods are expecting. Hope that helps.