# What's the differences between t.onclick = doSomething and t.onclick = doSomething() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript syntax: function calls and using parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis)

```
 t.onclick = doSomething 

 t.onclick = doSomething()
```

what's the different between the two event registrations?

sometimes I would confuse about them,add an parentheses seems would not cause big problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one assigns a reference to `doSomething` to the `onclick` property. The second assigns the *return value* of `doSomething`. That's unlikely to be what you want, unless `doSomething` returns a function.

Assign a reference:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("something");
}
//When t is clicked, "something" is logged
t.onclick = doSomething;
```

Assign the return value:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("something");
}
//"something" is logged immediately. When clicked, nothing happens
t.onclick = doSomething();
```

Assign a returned function:

```
function doSomething() {
    return function() {
        console.log("something");
    };
}
//When t is clicked, "something" is logged
t.onclick = doSomething();
```

Comment: So `doSomething()` should be better named as `returnSomethingNowWhichWillDoSomethingThen()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The manner in which you reference objects means a lot in JS. There's a difference between `doSomething;` and `doSomething();` because the first is referencing the function and the latter is referencing the `return value` of the function. Let's look at this example and you'll see what I mean. `doSomething();` not only invokes the function but returns the `return value` of the function:

```
function doSomething() {
    return 5;
}

console.log(doSomething); // function() { return 5; }

console.log(doSomething()); // 5
```

So doing `t.onclick = doSomething;` is very much like saying `t.onclick = function() { return 5; };`