# Auto populate select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I am trying to auto populate a select box using Jquery and JavaScript.

I done some searching and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery) and followed the advice of the selected answer.

I originally set up a jsFiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/GJdBR/

After receiving some advice on answers below I created a new jsfiddle and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/2UbqP/

However, on my computer I am using a clean install of windows 7, all I have done so far, is install chrome, apanta and xampp. I go to localhost/website and the site comes up, however the js functionality doesn't work, the select box isn't being filled with the var even though I proved the code is correct because of the jsfiddle above.

I am getting an error on this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    populateTranslationOptions();
});
```

The error reads:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. check this

```
function populateTranslationOptions ()
{
    var translationOptions = ["Egyptian Hieroglyphs", "Al Bhed (Final Fantasy X)", "Futurama"];
    $.each(translationOptions ,function(i,value) {   
        $('#translationOptions')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",value)
            .text(value)); 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   populateTranslationOptions();
 });​
```

Problems in your code:

- [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) syntax is wrong

  $.each(translationOptions (value)) {

Should be

```
$.each(translationOptions ,function(i,value) {
```

- You were not calling the function `populateTranslationOptions;` doesnt call the function 
  `populateTranslationOptions();` does.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/GJdBR/1/)

Comment: The page at https://127.0.0.1/Sites/Personal%20Website/fun-translator.php ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL funtranslator.js:14

Comment: What do you have in your funtranslator.js line 14?

Comment: the javascript found in the jsfiddle

Comment: The same code is working fine here, http://joynag.net/demos/fun/ , Can you copy the source of that page into `fun-translator.php` and check if it's working for you?

Comment: it works if i upload it which is why in the question i wondered if it was something about my xammp install

Comment: In the end i just remade the file. Thanks for all your help. am awarding you the bounty as you helped most.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(translationOptions, function (index, value) {   
        $('#translationOptions')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",value)
            .text(value)); 
    });
```

You've tried

```
$.each(translationOptions, (value) )
```

it's wrong, because correct structure is `$.each(mapData, callbackFunction)`, here `mapData` means Object or Array.

And next issue is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   populateTranslationOptions;
 });​
```

It should ne

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   populateTranslationOptions(); // you missed () here
 });​
```

Mind that, `populateTranslationOptions` doesn't call a function, so to call a function you need to `populateTranslationOptions()`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GJdBR/15/)**

#### One important note

> The () after a function means to execute the function itself and
> return it's value. Without it you simply have the function, which can
> be useful to pass around as a callback.

**Related refs:**

- **[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**
- **[call javascript function with/without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis)**

Answer (score 1):

For arrays, $.each is unnecessary. You can use a simple loop rather. Like as follows -

```
function populateTranslationOptions()
{
    var translationOptions = ["Egyptian Hieroglyphs", "Al Bhed (Final Fantasy X)", "Futurama"];
    for (var i = 0; i < translationOptions.length; i++) {
        $('#translationOptions')
            .append('<option value="' + translationOptions[i] + '">' + translationOptions[i] + '</option>');
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   populateTranslationOptions();
 });​
```