# HTML select elements not POSTED on submit

Tags: html, jsp, post, get

I am using HTML and JSP.

I have the following form:

```
<form   name="test" id="test" method="get" ACTION="result.jsp">

<input id="enteredGene" type="text" name="enteredGene" autocomplete="off" Style="position:absolute; top: 63px; left: 295px; width: 115px; margin-top: 6px; height: 22px; right: -4px;"/><br />

<input type="text" id="microarrayFileName" name="microarrayFileName" Style="position:absolute; top: 209px; left: 133px; width: 275px; margin-top: 6px; height: 22px; right: 250px;"  oninput="enableSubmit()"/><br />

 <select name= "insertGenes" id="insertGenes"  multiple="multiple" style="position:absolute; top: 103px; left: 138px; width: 275px; height: 71px;" onfocus="enableRemoveButton()">
         </select>
</form>
```

My problem is, when I submit the form, only the tags of type  "text" which are the first 2 tags are posted. The "select" element with the name "insertGenes" is not posted. I knew that by checking the Get list.

It only shows this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geneOntology/result.jsp?enteredGene=&microarrayFileName=GSM34635.pad
```

Why the select element is not posted? I also tried to get its value after the submit and I found it NULL.

I tried to add other select elements and they all have the same problem. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your select item has no `<option> ..</option>` elements

Comment: But I am getting the options in javascript during run time.

Comment: Yes, it worked when adding the options, but how can I make it work by adding the options in javascript?

Comment: see the first answer on this thread and the working fiddle..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872714/auto-populate-select-box

Comment: I did that by selecting all the values in the list on submit. Thanks.