# Implementation of onclick

Tags: javascript

Suppose that we have:

`<input type="button" name="button" value="Validate Payment" onclick="Validate()" />`

We can put in the onclick:

1. `onclick="Validate"`
2. `onclick="Validate()"`
3. `onclick="Validate();"`

My question is what is the difference between these 3 implementation

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this inline as an attribute of an HTML element?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button and see what it looks like in the bottom preview panel (I've done it for you this time).

Comment: The difference is the first one won't do anything.

Comment: As a side note, all three of your examples are bad practice. [Event handlers should always be bound in javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript_and_PHP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Will not execute the function, it will return the function (try: `console.log(Validate)`)
2. Will execute the function.
3. Will, exactly like #2, execute the function.

So there's no difference between #2 and #3, functionally.

Please note that inline event handlers are bad practice, [like mentioned in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610015/implementation-of-onclick/13610076#comment18659903_13610015) by [jbabey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386152/jbabey).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between onclick="Validate();" and onclick="Validate()" is non existant.  Semicolons are optional in javascript, so your code will be the same.

To understand the difference between onclick="Validate" and the other two, you need to understand a little about the use of parenthesis in Javascript.

Bascially,

```
onclick="Validate()"
```

will execute the function "Validate" and return whatever that function returns.

```
onclick="Validate"
```

will return the actual function "Validate".

See here for a fuller explaination: [javascript syntax: function calls and using parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis)

Comment: Actually, semicolons are for separating commands, and would be required if multiple function calls are passed.

Comment: But in the implementation above, the semicolon makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses `()` after the function name represent 'void', which is - at least by default - neccesary to execute the function properly. In some cases you would need to type in something between those parentheses, which is called 'passing a value' along with the function.

Since this (the 'void' thing) is almost, but not exactly, the same for a lot of similar programming languages (php, Actionscript, etc), and it's kind of a vague thing, I can't tell you exactly what this is for in JS though.

The difference between
`onclick="Validate()"`
and
`onclick="Validate();"` is in terms of functionality nothing. The semicolon `;` separates pieces of code from each other, so it would be required if you would call another function after the Validate() function. In this case, there's no difference betweeen `onclick="Validate()"` and
`onclick="Validate();"`.

Answer (score -2):

There's no difference between them.

Comment: Shoosh it if you don't know.

Comment: Actually, there is no difference, and your answer basically says exactly the same thing. Unlike a couple of the other answerers (it seems), I actually tested the 1st way, and it does work (in chrome 25 at least).

Comment: I take that back; I tried it on an existing page in chrome and it worked, however I created a page to test it and it didn't work then. Apologies; it may depend on the document mode.

Comment: Alright, no hard feelings :) See my answer to the question for a basic (I'm no expert on this either) explanation about the difference.