# Mozilla AFRAME a-frame launch inspector from button onclick instead keystroke

Tags: javascript, mozilla, aframe

We all know that you can launch the inspector using strg+alt+i, but I am right now trying to add a button to my user interface that does the same thing:

```
function customEnterInspector () {
        var scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
        if (scene) {
            if (scene.hasLoaded) {
                this.injectInspector();
            } else {
                scene.addEventListener('loaded', this.injectInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    $( "#intoinspector" ).click(function() {
        customEnterInspector();
    });
```

However, I do get the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: this.injectInspector is not a function
at customEnterInspector (index.html:925)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.html:933)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

I suppose the element (a-scene) that I am referencing is not the right one. I already tried with "window", but that didn't work either. Any advice on what I could else try?

Thanks & Best,
- Max

Comment: Side note on JS syntax: `foo.addListener('event', callback())` will not work, because `callback()` is called immediately, not passed to the listener. Instead, you'll want `foo.addListener('event', callback)`, which just hands the function to the listener so that it can be called later. Adding `()` makes the function run immediately, which we don't want. [More details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

This code is working great too.

```
function openEditor()
{
    window.postMessage('INJECT_AFRAME_INSPECTOR','*');
}
```

I have attached this function to a image that executes the previous code:

```
<input type="image" src="images/edit.png" width="35" height="35" onclick="openEditor();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `injectInspector()` method is part of the [`inspector` component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/e664fe651d4bc6ca7037ce7b0e83bcbc8628885b/src/components/scene/inspector.js) on the scene object. In the code snippet you've posted above, `this` is referring to the button element, which does not have that method. To refer to the component, you can do this:

```
 var inspector = scene.components.inspector;

 // Show inspector immediately.
 inspector.injectInspector();

 // Show inspector after event.
 scene.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
   inspector.injectInspector();
 });
```